# Outlook 365 displaying links beside text instead of making text clickable

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

For some reason, on all incoming messages, Outlook 365 (2016) in both preview and standard message view has started displaying links inside angle brackets beside the text that is supposed to be clickable.

It should look like this:

Hello [this](https://google.com) is a link.

But instead, it looks like this:

Hello this <https://google.com > is a link.

Screenshot:

[image]

Another screenshot of an advertisement from Sam's Club:
[image]

Outlook just started doing this in the last 2 days. I can't find a setting to change it - any ideas appreciated!

Comment: You possibly missing to enter the text in "text to display" filed, verify and try to doing that. Hope it works!

Comment: How do you insert the link? Does it show correctly when you compose the email?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify this is for *all incoming* messages. Not ones I compose.

Comment: @perry it is occurring on all incoming messages, not outgoing.

Comment: We can try opening Outlook in safe mode to see if the issue continues. Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /safe and then press Enter. This helps eliminate whether the problem lies on any third party add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have *Read all standard mail in plain text* checked in your Trust Center settings in Outlook.

Try the following:

1. Click *File* → *Options*.
2. Click the *Trust Center* tab.
3. Click the *Trust Center Settings…* button.
4. Click the *Email Security* tab.
5. Uncheck *Read all standard mail in plain text*.

[image: Outlook Options, Trust Center tab]
[image: Trust Center, Email Security tab]

Comment: Thanks for this tip - but unfortunately it didn't work.  This option was already disabled.  I even tried enabling, then disabling it again, but no luck.